# Echo is not showing full text?

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to get the value of one of the query key using echo. But it is not showing full text.

My program goes like this:

Generate Script

In script.php, I am writing:

The `getString` value is in encoded url. But the output is only showing partial text. I want to show full text.

Comment: You're not using echo.

Comment: Shot in the dark - it is displaying broken HTML [because it hasn't been escaped for output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  `echo htmlspecialchars($getString)`. View your page source, you'll probably find the full string.

Comment: thanks for the correction, I was changing it in notepad and forgot to edit here.

Comment: wow so many negative points ...

Answer (score 0):

Try

> printf("%s", $getString);

Printf accepts output format as first parameter.

Comment: True, but in this case it would also just accept the plain string $getSting with no `%` placeholders.